# can't leave virtual console

Tags: 16.04, hardware, virtual-console

I opened a virtual console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>:<kbd>F3</kbd> and now can't get back to the regular `X` display with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>:<kbd>F7</kbd>.

The screen is black, the fan is going, the power is on. The light on my mouse doesn't come on when I plug the mouse in.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F2` (first x session) or `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` (display manager). This has been changed with switch to systemd I think.